# Should I enable client_max_body_size, proxy_request_buffering and proxy_buffering?

Tags: 16.04, server, python, nginx

Should `client_max_body_size`, `proxy_request_buffering` and `proxy_buffering` be enabled on Ubuntu server when running Flask application? What `client_max_body_size` is recomented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of requests you are waiting from clients.

For example, if your application support file uploading, you should increase `client_max_body_size` to value of max allowed file size + 1Mb

I recommend to set increased `client_max_body_size` for specified location only.

```
location /my_upload_location/ {
    client_max_body_size   31m;
}
```

By default `client_max_body_size` = 1Mb. This means that any request from client can have `Content-Length` header with value less or equal 1Mb.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

You should enable `proxy_request_buffering` only if you have more then 1 application backend and need to resend request to another backend if first one return an error.

In other case enabling `proxy_request_buffering` just increase response time.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_request_buffering

Enabling `proxy_buffering` allow you to cache backend responses. If `proxy_buffering` is switched of nginx will not cache anything from your application backend.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering